# Bring back previous activity from stack and update it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I need to get previous activity from the stack and update it. Currently when I use `startActivity()` on second activity, opens the first one but will create new one, and by clicking back button, opens the first one (the one which not updated). How can I solve this problem?

**Activity A**

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
```

**Activity B**

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class).putExtra("profile", mProfile));
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: You want to go `A --> B --> update A`?

Comment: @codeMagic Yes I want to do that.

Comment: @SagarZala I updated my question with simple code.

Comment: That link above is what you want to do then

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class).putExtra("profile", mProfile).
setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));